# MySQL not running in my ubuntu terminal on windows 10. How to fix it?

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, ubuntu

I try running command `~$ mysql -u root -p`

But the following error comes along-`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)`

I have already installed mysql-client and mysql-server.Even it is not working

Comment: what is an "ubuntu terminal on windows 10"?

Comment: window subsystem for linux

Answer (score 0):

Start deamon `sudo systemctl start mysql` or run `mysql -u root -p` as root